# mySQL while looping code doesn't work it always echo "it failed"?

Tags: php, mysql

when i run the code it only displays the echo which says it failed, i think there is no missing brackets or quotation marks

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id1242269_sql", "pass", "id1242269_sql");
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
     die("Could not connect to database");
} 

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
if ($result=mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} else {
    echo "it failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: Print the reason for the failure: `echo mysqli_error($link);`

Comment: username ,password and database name is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

This is where [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) comes in handy.

```
if ($result=mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} else {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link)); // Print error message
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. And I already commented about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id1242269_sql", "pass", "id1242269_sql");
```

I am new to this but in my homework we used "new" in there too:

```
$link = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "id1242269_sql", "pass", "id1242269_sql");
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the connection:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id1242269_sql", "pass", "id1242269_sql");
```

Worked fine for me with this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testDb");
```

My Result: 
[image]

Comment: You should use correct username and password as well as the database name. Rest code is fine .